# Is it okay to store JSX.Element in useState?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is it okay to do the following?

```
const Foo: FC = () => {
    [myState, setMyState] = useState<JSX.Element | null>(null)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setMyState(<p>Hi</p>)
    }, [])

    return myState
}
```

I have tried this and it does work, however I can't find any resources on whether or not this is a good practice, or if this has any consequences in terms of performance or anything like that.

Comment: As long as the component isn't instaciated like: `setState(<Component />)` and just a reference `setState(Component)` there is no problem. In your case the state is just an **jsx expression** so it is valid react code

Comment: It may work, but it's really weird. I'd recommend against it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you want a reference to an element after it is rendered, this is not the way to do it.

Comment: @zero298 I'm trying to render component conditionally, or have a state that has list of components, where I can add more elements into based on the data I have.

Comment: let me know if I solved your problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't recommend it.

States should be data values. If you wanted certain components to render conditionally, refer to the state values(data) to decide the cases.

Comment: Assume you want to set a custom element in a footer or sidebar, and you want any child component to be able to do that. One solution would be to use a context which also delivers a callback to forward the object to the setter function we got from `useState(null as JSX.Element | null)`. Would this be considered as good practice? How else would it be possible to achieve something like this as passing data alone would not suffice in such a case.